# Help identifying something in guitar tablature?

Tags: guitar, tablature, fingerstyle-guitar

[image: Tab]

Hey, I'm having trouble identifying what those two arcs are. The dotted one going over and the solid one going under.

I'm trying to re-create this tab in Guitar Pro 6, so that I can listen to it as it helps me play better.

This is the tab for the song Layover by Michael Hedges from Andy McKee's Joyland tablature book.

Comment: The octave sign seems to me to indicate that you should play the artificial harmonic an octave higher.

Comment: @NeilMeyer - that's the only way it'll sound - an octave higher than written.

Answer (score 2):

They are both just ties to indicate that you sustain the note for 4+2+1.5 beats (or an eight note less than two bars).  The dashed one is dashed because it applies to the harmonic notes.  Note that you hold the F on the 6th string against the fretboard, but induce a harmonic at the 7th fret.

The wavy vertical line indicates that the "chord" should be rapidly arpeggiated -- in this case it means that the harmonic note should be played ever so slightly after the fretted note.

Comment: Any ideas how the arpeggiation wavy lines should be played?

Comment: F normally? It's normally on 1st fret, but this is tuned to open D. The harmonic will work on 7th OR 19th fret without the jiggery pokery. Use l.h. above fret 7, or, easier, use r.h. above fret 19. OR - 5th fret harm. on B string - less stretch!

Comment: @NeilMeyer - just play the lower note slightly before the upper.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'm not sure if you use Guitar Pro 6, or any version at all, but do you have any idea on how to mimic that tie in the program? I was playing around with it, but can't seem to get it right. Like I said, I'm putting the tab into GP6, so I can listen to while I play it.